# Print a binary search tree as a single string

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

There's a practice problem that I've been working on that's been confusing me.

Define a function treeLevelOrder which satisfies the following claim:
If Q is a binary search tree of integers, then treeLevelOrder(Q) is the String representation of the contents of Q according to their level in the tree. 
 We get this tree as an example

```
      9
   /     \
  5       16
 / \     /  \
1   7   12  19
```

The value of the expression treeLevelOrder(Q) in this case would be
"[9,5,16,1,7,12,19]".

I've seen similar problems, but they don't follow the same format that I'm looking for, wanting to print by level order or as ordered tuples. Here's some sample code I've been working on:

```
 private String treeLevelOrder(Node Q)
 {
   if (Q.left == null && Q.right == null)
       return "[" + Q.datum + "]";
   else if (Q.left == null && Q.right != null)
       return "[" + Q.datum + ", "+Q.right.datum+"]" + treeLevelOrder(Q.right);
   else if (Q.left !=null && Q.right == null)
       return"[" + Q.datum + ", "+Q.left.datum+", *]"+ treeLevelOrder(T.left);
   else
       return "[" + Q.datum + ", "+Q.left.datum+", "+Q.right.datum+"]" + 
              treeLevelOrder(Q.left) + treeLevelOrder(Q.right);          
 }
```

Any assistance would be helpful.

EDIT: Okay, so I've been experimenting with the level order example at [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/), thank you curlyBraces, that would be closer to what I'm looking for, though I can't figure out to make it return a string. Here's the code they use:

```
/* function to print level order traversal of tree*/
void printLevelOrder()
{
    int h = height(root);
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=h; i++)
        printGivenLevel(root, i);
}
/* Compute the "height" of a tree -- the number of
nodes along the longest path from the root node
down to the farthest leaf node.*/
int height(Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
       return 0;
    else
    {
        /* compute  height of each subtree */
        int lheight = height(root.left);
        int rheight = height(root.right);        
        /* use the larger one */
        if (lheight > rheight)
            return(lheight+1);
        else return(rheight+1); 
    }
}
/* Print nodes at the given level */
void printGivenLevel (Node root ,int level)
{
    if (root == null)
        return;
    if (level == 1)
        System.out.print(root.data + ", ");
    else if (level > 1)
    {
        printGivenLevel(root.left, level-1);
        printGivenLevel(root.right, level-1);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation using while loop and two queues to keep track of all the nodes:

```
    public String treeLevelOrder(Node root) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
        Queue<Node> current = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Node> other = new LinkedList<>();
        if(root != null)
            current.add(root);

        while(!current.isEmpty()) {
            while(!current.isEmpty()) {
                Node node = current.remove();
                result.append(",");
                result.append(node.datum);

                // adding children to the other queue
                if(node.left != null)
                    other.add(node.left);
                if(node.right != null)
                    other.add(node.right);
            }

            // swapping the queues
            Queue<Node> temp = current;
            current = other;
            other = temp;
        }

        // building final string
        if(result.length() == 0)
            result.append("[");
        else
            result.setCharAt(0,'[');
        result.append("]");
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Not to sound demanding, but I haven't covered queues yet. I've seen recursive versions from the other questions I reviewed. Is there one for this too?

Comment: I found an alternative solution here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/. Checkout the method 1. It first calculates the height of the tree using recursion. Then it prints each level iteratively.

Comment: It's nice, but the problem looks more like it wants one method that takes each node as it appears in the tree and then adds it to a string. I keep looking for examples but everything is either ascending order or printing on multiple levels.

Comment: Thinking about it now, I wonder if it would be easier to put the values of the BST into an array, and output that as a string?